# Custom Wordpressplugin causes trouble with nginx rewrite

Tags: wordpress, plugins, nginx

I have a big problem with nginx and it's wordpress-rules for redirecting/permalinks.

So here is what we have:

1. A blog using permalinks (/%category%/%postname%/)
2. nginx
3. A custom plugin (product comparision) which was coded on a dev-system

Under normal circumstances we just need to use the following nginx-line:

```
try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
```

But it does not work with the new plugin! I mean I can access all categorys, posts and so on.

Now when the plugin is used there is another section (page) where users can compare different products. The problem is, that this plugin uses the following linkstructure:
/compare/product-name/123 
123 is the product-ID.

On the dev-system we did just this:

```
rewrite ^/compare/([a-z0-9-]+)/([0-9]+)?$ /?page_id=32134&id=$2 break;
```

This worked just fine (on the dev-system where the permalink feature wasnt active).

After activating the permalink stuff and adding

```
rewrite ^/compare/([a-z0-9-]+)/([0-9]+)?$ /?page_id=PAGEIDOFLIVESYSTEM&id=$2 break;
location / {
try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
}
```

to my nginx conf, wordpress says that it could not find an article.

I think there is a conflict with the rewrite rules, but I have no idea how to solve it after trying different stuff.

Maybe someone has a good idea!

Regards & excuse my bad english!

Bye

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for the answer!

I found a solution by myself a day ago.
The problem was the plugin, which uses own rules but does not register them on wordpress. I used a plugin which allows me to add new rules and put them "on position one"/make them more important than others.

Second issue was an unknown $_GET-Var, which needed to be registered on wordpress. Monkeyman Rewrite Plugin helped me find that out!

After doing both things, I just needed to add 
rewrite ^/compare/([a-z0-9-]+)/([0-9]+)?$ /compare-site-name?id=$2 break;
to my nginx-conf!

Thats the magic...

Maybe I can help someone with this solution on some (I think) bad written plugins!

Bye

Answer (score 0):

I never understood the `try_files` that uses `?args`, I always use `$request_uri` instead, you should try it

```
try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$reqiest_uri;
```